# How to enable Chrome's "continue where you left off" for OS X El Capitan?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I need Chrome to restore last session tabs after closing its whole window. 
Simple "continue where you left off" does not work when I close Chrome's window.

I was looking for the resolution but all I got is useless answers provided by apple fanboys "that is the proper way - closing window does not mean closing a program". Sincerly, I don't accept it.

How to achieve proper behaviour of "continue where you left off"?

Comment: So...   as part of asking for help, you insult the Apple Community and call us "fanboys"?

Comment: And yes...  closing a windows (Command - W) is not the same as closing out the whole program (Command - Q).   If you have the "continue where you left off" option selected in Chrome, and you quit Chrome...  you should get the tabs that were there previously.

Comment: Maybe it makes more sense this way… If you close the window instead of quitting the app, then "where you left off" is with that window closed.

Answer (score 15):

First, you want to make sure the setting is enabled in Chrome.    In the upper left corner of the screen, you'll want to click on Chrome -> Preferences and make sure the "continue where you left off" button is checked.

Next, please do understand there is a difference between closing a window and closing a program.   <kbd>Command</kbd> - <kbd>Q</kbd> is used to exit a program completely.    In OS X, if you close a window using the "red x" in the upper left corner, you are closing out a window, and not the program.

To see this work correctly...  try opening 3-4 tabs.   Then press  <kbd>Command</kbd> - <kbd>Q</kbd>.    Then relaunch Chrome.   You should see all your tabs there.

Answer (score 9):

To add to a previous answer ([one by Charlie74](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/218172/60161)), if you happen to accidentally close the window using the red x at the top, you can quickly get back all your tabs by using <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>. This is usually used to reopen a recently closed tab, but also works to reopen a recently closed window.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what you are asking, but to get Chrome to resuming its last state:

Chrome > Settings Page (chrome://settings) > On Startup > Continue where you left off.